# url not working without https/http in aws elasticbeanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have hosted a website on AWS using elastic beanstalk.
I have registered a domain from aws route 53(abfrlawards2020.com) and ssl certificate from aws as well
I am using nodejs as backend.
It works properly if I write http://example.com or https://example.com but when I just write abfrlawards2020.com on address bar it doesnot work it just keeps loading

Comment: How did you set http listener on your load balancer?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a stupid question actually when I was creating inbound rules in security group I accidentally created the https rule twice and didnot add port 80(http) to the security group. still I am keepig this question so if someone does a stupid mistake like this this may help them.